# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why: inside docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have a docker container like the following:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.2
```

when I go inside the container by docker run -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash and run

```
gem install rails
```

I'm getting the following error:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

A solution that I found was by doing

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

but it didn't work

I also tried

```
gem update --system
```

but also didn't work and threw me the error

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Outside the container the command worked fine. By the way I'm running docker 19.03.5. Also this happens with any gem.

What could be the source of the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine3.10

RUN apk update \
  && apk add --virtual build-dependencies \
  imagemagick \
  gcc \
  wget \
  git \
  && apk add \
  build-base postgresql-dev tzdata less \
  bash

RUN gem install rails

WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "/app/config/puma.rb"]
```

Comment: Hi there! thanks for aswering. I tried the following now:

I enter the container same way I explained on my question
Then I created a Gemfile with the following

"source 'https://rubygems.org
gem 'rails'

After that I ran bundle install, but I still get an error like:

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Comment: Can you explain to me the whole point of the task?  Maybe I'll help you.

Comment: My goal is to have a container for ruby on rails development.

Comment: And use `bundle exec` in container. You have any questions?

Comment: I will test it today! I just didn't undestand why should I reinstall docker..

Comment: I can be exaggerated.  but just in case, you can reinstall)

Comment: I'll try that out, but without doing the reinstall I'm getting the same error: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Yes, I can be exaggerated. Do not reinstall docker)

Comment: Actually it did work... I just wish I knew why.. hehehe thanks for the help! do you know any reason why that might have been happening?

Comment: Pls, upvote my solution, and mark mine as the right decision

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." That's I've got...